# How to get the default gateway from powershell?

Tags: powershell

If a computer has multiple gateways, how can I determine which is the default gateway using the PowerShell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to know which of the multiple gateways are used? If so. From what I remember, when multiple gateways are available the gateway with the lowest metric("cost" based on link speed) is used. To get this, run the following command:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable |
  where { $_.destination -eq '0.0.0.0' -and $_.mask -eq '0.0.0.0'} |
  Sort-Object metric1 | select nexthop, metric1, interfaceindex
```

if there are multiple default gateways with the same cost, I think it's decided using the binding order of the network adapters. The only way I know to get this is using GUI and registry. To include binding order you could save the output of the script over, get the settingsid from Win32_networkadapterconfiguration (identify using interfaceindex), and read the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage\Bind. This key lists the binding order it seems, and the settingsid you get from win32_networkadapterconfiguration is the GUID they identify the device with. Then sort the gateways with equal metrics using their order in the Bind reg.key and you got your answer.

Explained in: [Technet Social - NIC adapter binding](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sr-Latn-CS/ITCG/thread/764fee15-9e22-4a46-b284-9f63f774a5e4)

Answer (score 18):

If you're on PowerShell v3, you can use `Get-NetIPConfiguration` e.g.:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration | Foreach IPv4DefaultGateway
```

Comment: The Net/IP Cmdlets are available from Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 onwards.

Answer (score 14):

I think this will be more cross platform:

```bsh
 Get-NetRoute |
    where {$_.DestinationPrefix -eq '0.0.0.0/0'} |
    select { $_.NextHop }
```

Comment: This is expressive, but you can get the same result with a little less typing: `(Get-NetRoute "0.0.0.0/0").NextHop`

Answer (score 5):

I found it as the below which lists all active gateways, correct me if I am wrong

```
(Get-wmiObject Win32_networkAdapterConfiguration | ?{$_.IPEnabled}).DefaultIPGateway
```

Comment: it is correct if that was what you asked for. Question was unclear. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the WMI queries to pull the data that you're looking for.  Below is a fairly simple example to pull the default gateway for a device specified in the first line variable.  This will query the device for network adapters and display the found information (for each adapter) to the console window - pulls adapter index, adapter description, and default gateway

Shouldn't take much to expand this to process multiple devices, or process based on a list fed via an input file.

```
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Get-WmiObject win32_networkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | 
Select index,description,defaultipgateway |
Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ActiveNet =  Get-NetAdapter –Physical  |Where-Object {$_.status -eq "Up"} |  select name 

$Network = Get-NetIPAddress |Where-Object EnabledDefault -EQ 2 | Where-Object InterfaceAlias  -EQ $ActiveNet.name  | Where-Object IPv4Address -NE $null | select * 

$DefautGateway = Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $Network.InterfaceIndex -DestinationPrefix "0.0.0.0/0" | select NextHop

$DefautGateway.NextHop
```