# Routing and VPN

Tags: powershell, vpn

I have created a powershell script to create a VPN, connect to add, add the routes for it.

The only issue I am having is that my gateway for that VPN is not known upfront, so users need to add it with a parameter.

This isn't so clean, so I would like to retrieve the gateway from the VPN connection in PowerShell. Is there any way to this?

I am connecting to my VPN like this "rasphone.exe -d $name".
How can I obtain the gateway for this VPN so I can route certain IP's through the VPN?

Comment: you mean like in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869182/how-to-get-the-default-gateway-from-powershell)?

Comment: This gives you the default Gateway. I am using a Splitted VPN tunnel, because a only want certain traffic to be routed through the VPN.
If I would use this default gateway, traffic will not be routed through VPN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a working approach:

First I need to get the IP configuration for the VPN connection

```
$ipConfiguration = Get-NetIPConfiguration | where { $_.InterfaceAlias -eq $name } | Select-Object -First 1
```

Than I can add routes for this VPN like this:

```
ROUTE.EXE ADD $ip MASK $mask $ipConfiguration.IPv4Address.IPAddress if $ipConfiguration.interFaceIndex;
```

The IP address is not the actual gateway, but in the docs I have read that the closed gateway is taken. This works perfectly!