# Default Gateway Manipulation

Tags: powershell, network-programming

Goal:
Looking to pass the value of the default gateway into a variable for another call using PowerShell. Something like `$var1 = <whatever command that will work>` so I can then call `$var1` later in another statement.

Steps Looked into:

1. `Get-NetIPConfiguration` - Within this, I see the IPv4DefaultGateway option and looking at the `| gm` I can see the reference to a ciminstance, but when I use a command such as the following:

   ```
   $NetworkAdapterConfigurationList = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration;
   $NetworkAdapterConfigurationList | Select-Object -Property DefaultIPGateway
   ```

   I get this output:

   ```
   DefaultIPGateway
   ‐---------------
   {10.1.80.1}
   ```

   And when I attempt to pass that to a variable, it shows up as "TypeName: Selected.Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance" instead of a String; and [string] doesn't seem to fix it.
2. Tried performing something similar using `Get-NetRoute`:

   ```
   Get-NetRoute | Select-Object NextHop -Unique
   ```

   ```
   NextHop
   ‐------
   0.0.0.0
   10.1.60.1
   10.1.80.1
   ::
   ```

   But then couldn't figure out how to parse it back to only give me the 10.1.80.1 gateway.

Ideas? Comments? Wondering if I can do this with Regex or something now that I got it this far, or am I over thinking it?

**Edit:** Someone did point me over to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869182/how-to-get-the-default-gateway-from-powershell), but I have already did the steps suggested, but it's coming out as a ciminstance, rather than a string.

Comment: What about [How to get the default gateway from powershell?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13869182)

Comment: The link you referenced, (Get-NetIPConfiguration | Foreach IPv4DefaultGateway)  I already did in Step 1 as far as the output is shown. I'll add that to my question's notes though. It does give me some of the data, but I need to then have it pass as a string only showing the gateway, not the whole list/CIM value.

Comment: Actually, all you need is `-ExpandProperty` instead of `-Property` in the first snippet.